# When/how to start farm Wraiths on Mid Lane?

Tags: league-of-legends

Good players in higher elo start farming wraiths and wolves quite out from midlane quite early. Actually I can't explain myself how they actually manage to do so. When I start to farm Wraiths pre-Level 8 and I don't have blue, clearing the camp in a decent time drains half my mana, because I need all spells to come back to lane in time and I don't take to much damage.
So my question is, when should I start farming wraiths (when I have a Mana Champ), so that it doesn't have to many impact on my lane itself? (Assuming I don't have blue and the lane is going "normal")

Comment: A quick note that the Season 3 jungle changes both move the location of the large wraith and decrease the XP and Gold values of the Wraith camp, making farming them while in mid lane somewhat less feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your effectiveness at clearing jungle creeps depends primarily on two things: your champ, and whether you have blue.

Some champs can farm up wraiths and wolves more effectively than others. Post-6 Anivia with blue, for example, clears camps quickly and easily, whereas Kassadin has a bit more trouble. If you don't have blue, the number of champs that can easily and quickly farm camps decreases.

Above all, though, make sure you communicate with your jungler. Some junglers will be more than happy to let you have wraiths, but some junglers might want/need the farm. It's always polite to ask. Pissing off your jungler is never a good idea.

As to *when* you should farm wraiths, that depends entirely on the dynamic of the lane. If the lane is not pushed to the enemy tower, you should stay mid and farm; you'll get more experience and gold that way (unless you're someone like Anivia and have blue, in which case you can probably sneak away to grab jungle creeps and come out on top for it). If the lane is pushed to the enemy tower, you have four options:

1) Attack turret. Taking mid turret early gives your jungler a lot of breathing room, and gives the enemy jungler a headache.

2) Ganking top or mid. You'll see this a lot in high-level play. Most mids are powerful gankers, and this is a great way to help out your teammates (while often giving you more gold and xp!)

3) Going back and buying. Sitting on 2000 gold? It won't do you a lick of good if you don't spend it.

4) Taking jungle creeps.

Just because you *can* farm jungle creeps doesn't mean you *should*. Often a gank top or bot is more effective.

Comment: I completely agree with you. Please don't steal a junglers camps. If you are winning your own lane feel free to bank though, getting a kill is much more worth it than a camp. I find it better to just never farm camps. Leave them for your jungler, go get a gank and push a lane. Even if you don't get a kill but you get a lane pushed it is much more valuable in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Not every mid champ can farm wraith effectively without blue, you need to following quality:

- manaless or aoe ability don't require much mana or ability return mana on kill/hit
- possess good aoe ability, for example Morde or Morgana

These are a partial list of champs I think can farm wraith effectively after level 2:

- 1st tier: Morde, Morgana, Cass, Ziggs
- 2nd tier: Vlad, Sion, Malz, Kat

Comment: I'd expect Ziggs would need at least level 4 to farm wraiths, and even then it'd be time-consuming (not to mention mana-consuming). Vlad certainly can't farm wraiths quickly until he gets a few levels of his E. Sion is the same issue. Meanwhile, you forgot Anivia and Karthus. Level 2 is a bit of a silly cut-off anyway; most games (at least, >1200 elo) will feature a jungler, and mid won't be farming wraiths until level 6 or later. By that time, mana hungry champs will have a Chalice (if not blue).

Comment: I'd think Zyra at level 3 or 4 would be fairly easy, just put in two seeds and your spitters and cash in some free gold. Brand is good too with his pillar of flame.

Comment: To the person two above^^, Vlad can definitely at level 2 or 3. E wouldn't be that helpful :/ Q is what you need, + a hextech revolver i guess if you want to overuse your damage inducing E. E's really a special use ability. Also, vlad doesn't take mana AND his Q heals him. So yeah its not the fastest but man he goes away full everything ;) Anivia is for surely super quick but not until level 6. Level 2 is a silly cut-off for sure though.

Comment: Whether or not a champ CAN do it doesn't mean they should. Vlad clearing wraiths at level 2 or 3 would be horribly, horribly slow. Speed is an important factor. It could _theoretically_ be useful at that point to heal up, but if you desperately need to heal at that point, you're almost always better off just recalling.